# How can I split my controller name for url routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I want to split my controller name..

*For Example;*

My controller name is For_ExpController.cs

and

I want my url like this;

```
http://localhost/For/Exp/Action
```

How can I define it on my RouteConfig.cs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class MyRoute: Route
{
    public MyRoute()
        : base(
            "{part1}_{part2}/{action}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "for_exp", action = "index" }),
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { part1 = @"[a-z]+", part2 = @"[a-z]+" }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()
        )
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var part1 = rd.GetRequiredString("part1");
        var part2 = rd.GetRequiredString("part2");
        rd.Values["controller"] = string.Concat(part1, "_", part2);
        return rd;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in your `Application_Start`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("MyRoute", new MyRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```